# What does this wildcard syntax of CSS attribute selector mean?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's take this syntax as the object

```
.row-fluid[class*="span"] {
    display: block;
}
```

My question what `class*="span"` means?

I guess the whole selector means picking up all HTML elements that have marked with class `row-fluid` and have any attribute starting with `class` whose value is `span` - though I'm not sure...

And if we have HTML block as

```
<div id='div01' class='row-fluid' class2='span' />
<div id='div02' class='row-fluid span' />
```

will the above selector matches both of them? Or only `#div01` matches?

Comment: Just read the documentation (at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). However, this is not the recommended to way to check for the presence of the `span` class, assuming that's what you want to do. For instance, this will match `class='span1'` or `class='rowspan'`. If you want to check for the `span` class, select classes in the normal way, as `.row-fluid.span`.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks. Please refer BoltClock answer which answers my OP http://stackoverflow.com/a/35593116/248616

Comment: You're welcome. Why didn't you just try this, instead of posting a question to SO? By the way `*=` is **NOT** called an "operator", to be precise. the term "operator" is used nowhere in the CSS grammar.

Comment: @torazaburo: Fine, I changed it to "token". That was my fault, not the OP's, and really should have been directed at me.

Comment: All that make up the best knowledge for everyone. Thanks @torazaburo and BoltClock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard match happens in the attribute value, not the attribute name. So only `#div02` will match — `#div01` will *not* match.

The `*` in the attribute selector refers to the [`*=` token](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings). It's not a wildcard within the attribute name like `class*`.

Comment: This is crystal clear explaination - the `*= operator` not the `wildcard attribute name`